# RELEASE and DEBUG build in makefile

Tags: makefile, stm32cubeide

I am developing an application for STM32 in stm32cubeIDE

I am using the below custom makefile. Now i want to have a release and a debug build, but they both build the debug build.

I´ve tried

```
RELDIR = bin/release
DEBUGDIR = bin/debug

ifdef DEBUG
BIN=$(DEBUGDIR)
COMPILERFLAGS += -g3 -O0 -D_DEBUG
else
BIN=$(RELDIR)
COMPILERFLAGS += -O3
endif
```

and

```
debug : rebuild
BIN=$(DEBUGDIR)
COMPILERFLAGS += -g3 -O0 -D_DEBUG

release : rebuild
BIN=$(RELDIR)
COMPILERFLAGS += -O3
```

Can someone tell me how to achieve a release and a debug build :)

Full script:

```
RED = [31m
GREEN = [32m
YELLOW = [33m
BLUE = [34m
NC = [0m

BIN = bin
SRC = src
INC = inc

SOURCE = $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)
OBJECT = $(patsubst %,$(BIN)/%, $(notdir $(SOURCE:.c=.o)))

COMPILER=arm-none-eabi-gcc
ARCHITECTURE=cortex-m4
COMPILERFLAGS= -c -mcpu=$(ARCHITECTURE) -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -std=gnu11 -Wall -I $(INC)
LINKERFLAGS= -mcpu=$(ARCHITECTURE) -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft --specs=nano.specs --specs=rdimon.specs -lc -lrdimon --specs=nosys.specs -T stm32_linker_script.ld -Wl,-Map=out.map

COMPILE= $(COMPILER) $(COMPILERFLAGS) -o $@ $<
LINK= $(COMPILER) $(LINKERFLAGS) -o $@ $^

RELDIR = bin/release
DEBUGDIR = bin/debug

ifdef DEBUG
BIN=$(DEBUGDIR)
COMPILERFLAGS += -g3 -O0 -D_DEBUG
else
BIN=$(RELDIR)
COMPILERFLAGS += -O3
endif

debug : rebuild
#BIN=$(DEBUGDIR)
#COMPILERFLAGS += -g3 -O0 -D_DEBUG
#
release : rebuild
#BIN=$(RELDIR)
#COMPILERFLAGS += -O3

.PHONY: rebuild
rebuild:
    $(MAKE) clean
    $(MAKE) all 

all : out.elf
    @echo "$(GREEN)Done!$(NC)"
    
out.elf : $(OBJECT)
    @echo "$(YELLOW)Linking...$(NC)"
    $(LINK)
    
$(BIN)/%.o : $(SRC)/%.c
    $(COMPILE)

.PHONY: all clean debug prep release remake
clean:
    @echo "$(GREEN)Cleaning...$(NC)"
    rm -rf $(BIN)/*.o $(BIN)/*.elf
```

Comment: How are you invoking `make` when you want a debug build?

Comment: I set the IDE up to call "make release" and "make debug" from the IDE (properties c/c++ build/behavior). It behaves the same when called form the console.

Comment: Well, that's not good enough.  In your makefile you have `ifdef DEBUG`, which means that to enable the debug build the `DEBUG` make variable needs to be set.  Just running `make debug`, by itself, is not enough to set a variable named `DEBUG`.  You need to have something that sets that variable.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating two makefiles, one for debug and one for release. It is kind of anoying to have duplicated code, but at least it is obvious what is going on in each script. The scripts are then called from the IDE via "make -f Makefile.DEBUG.mk rebuild" and "make -f Makefile.REBUILD.mk rebuild"

```
#RED = [31m
#GREEN = [32m
#YELLOW = [33m
BLUE = [34m
NC = [0m

BIN = bin/release
SRC = src
INC = inc

MAKE = make -f Makefile.RELEASE.mk

COMPILER=arm-none-eabi-gcc
ARCHITECTURE=cortex-m4

COMPILERFLAGS= -c -mcpu=$(ARCHITECTURE) \
    -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -std=gnu11 -Wall -O3 -I $(INC)

LINKERFLAGS= -mcpu=$(ARCHITECTURE) \
    -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft \
    --specs=nano.specs \
    -T stm32_linker_script.ld \
    -Wl,-Map=$(BIN)/out.map

COMPILE= $(COMPILER) $(COMPILERFLAGS) -o $@ $<
LINK= $(COMPILER) $(LINKERFLAGS) -o $(BIN)/$@ $^
SOURCE = $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)
OBJECT = $(patsubst %,$(BIN)/%, $(notdir $(SOURCE:.c=.o)))

.PHONY: rebuild
rebuild:
    $(MAKE) clean
    $(MAKE) all 

all : out.elf
    @echo "$(BLUE)Done!$(NC)"
    
out.elf : $(OBJECT)
    @echo "$(BLUE)Linking...$(NC)"
    $(LINK)
    
$(BIN)/%.o : $(SRC)/%.c
    $(COMPILE)

.PHONY: all clean
clean:
    @echo "$(BLUE)Cleaning...$(NC)"
    rm -rf $(BIN)/*.o $(BIN)/*.elf $(BIN)/*.map



and

#RED = [31m
#GREEN = [32m
#YELLOW = [33m
BLUE = [34m
NC = [0m

BIN = bin/debug
SRC = src
INC = inc

MAKE = make -f Makefile.DEBUG.mk

COMPILER=arm-none-eabi-gcc
ARCHITECTURE=cortex-m4

COMPILERFLAGS= -c -mcpu=$(ARCHITECTURE) \
    -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -std=gnu11 -Wall -g -I $(INC)

LINKERFLAGS= -mcpu=$(ARCHITECTURE) \
    -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft \
    --specs=nano.specs \
    --specs=rdimon.specs -lc -lrdimon \
    --specs=nosys.specs \
    -T stm32_linker_script.ld \
    -Wl,-Map=$(BIN)/out.map

COMPILE= $(COMPILER) $(COMPILERFLAGS) -o $@ $<
LINK= $(COMPILER) $(LINKERFLAGS) -o $(BIN)/$@ $^
SOURCE = $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)
OBJECT = $(patsubst %,$(BIN)/%, $(notdir $(SOURCE:.c=.o)))

.PHONY: rebuild
rebuild:
    $(MAKE) clean
    $(MAKE) all 

all : out.elf
    @echo "$(BLUE)Done!$(NC)"
    
out.elf : $(OBJECT)
    @echo "$(BLUE)Linking...$(NC)"
    $(LINK)
    
$(BIN)/%.o : $(SRC)/%.c
    $(COMPILE)

.PHONY: all clean
clean :
    @echo "$(BLUE)Cleaning...$(NC)"
    rm -rf $(BIN)/*.o $(BIN)/*.elf $(BIN)/*.map
```